# css padding compatibility firefox 9 chromium 15

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, anchor, padding

I'm using css gradients and padding to simulate buttons around an anchor tag. The problem I am running into is that firefox seems to make the button 3 pixels larger. 1 pixel on top and 2 on bottom. This seems to happen with not only the example i posted but everywhere on the page where i use the padding. I put up and example at http://wemw.net/example.php. In firefox the button top and bottom line up perfectly with the search box, but in chrome as i said its off by 1 pixel on top and 2 on bottom. I am using the w3 transitional(tried strict as well) doctype and a css reset. In the reset all anchor tags are set to padding: 0, so I'm confused as to why this extra padding is being added. Is there a workaround to this or is it just something you have to deal with when working with gecko and webkit browsers?

EDIT: So I logged over to windows and it is appearing the same in both browsers now. I'm assuming it is OS specific problems? Since no where near as many people use linux I'm going to change the padding to make it work, but in the interest of consistency can anyone offer a solution for cross-os cross-browser solutions? I do not own a mac and cannot easily test it there, but if windows/linux can have problems with the same versions of the same browsers is it safe to assume mac could also have issues i am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the padding on the anchor tag, it's the size of the text box that is inconsistent. `<input>` elements always caused such problems for me too, and I always found it extremely tedious to align them together nicely (you haven't yet seen it in IE8, have you?). I think that the easiest cross-browser solution here would be to remove the border from the text box and use a background image instead (or better yet, a background image on the element containing the text box) properly aligned with the button.